# GarageBand is unusable - "Maximum number of tracks (1000)"

Tags: audio, garageband

Only weeks after getting it, I can no longer use GarageBand on my brand new MBP 14" M1 Pro (macOS 12.1) because any attempt to create a new project immediately results in the error "Maximum Number of Software Instruments - You have added the maximum number of software instruments tracks (1000)". I also get this error when attempting to create a new track in any existing project.  (Obviously I have nowhere near 1000 tracks in any of these projects). I also sporadically get the message on launch: "A plugin has reported a problem. Please quit and restart GarageBand". These two issues began at the same time.

After doing some of my own research I tried restarting Core Audio via `sudo killall coreaudiod` and `sudo launchctl start com.apple.audio.coreaudiod` and restarting, but this has made no difference.  I do not have any external audio interfaces or third-party plugins.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did GarageBand show this error as soon as you started using it on your new M1 MBP?

Comment: @IconDaemon No, I was able to use it normally for a few weeks until this began happening.

Comment: What version of GarageBand are you running? You should also read this [Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201532) about Audio Units plug-ins. Essentially `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components` and `~/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components` may contain plug-ins which are not compatible. Try moving plug-ins one by one out of these folders into a temporary folder to find if one of them is causing the problem.

Comment: @IconDaemon I am running GarageBand 10.4.5 and both of those folders are empty.

Comment: Create a new user on your Mac and see if the error occurs when you run GarageBand as that user. If it works, then there is a preference file somewhere in your account that is wonky.

Answer (score 1):

Launch Terminal and type this command:

```
defaults delete com.apple.garageband10
```

Restart your Mac, this should resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).